# "Substituted for" versus "substituted"

Tags: difference, verbs

> Jair substituted *for* Kitty on Saturday, and Corny had a lot of fun.

> Jair substituted Kitty on Saturday, and Corny had a lot of fun.

Is *for* mandatory in the first sentence? If not, do those sentences have different meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences can have different meanings, although they are both ambiguous.

> Jair substituted for Kitty.

usually means

> Jair acted as a replacement for Kitty.

whereas

> Jair substituted Kitty

usually means

> Jair replaced Kitty [with somebody else]

The difference is that in the second sentence, it is possible (but not certain) that Jair was the person who acted as the replacement. In the first sentence Jair is more strongly indicated as the replacement himself/herself.

HOWEVER! Neither sentence is completely unambiguous as written, and the meaning could change depending on the context of surrounding sentences.

For instance

> Jair stood on the sidelines and saw Kitty was getting tired. He realised it was time he substituted for Kitty, and sent Corny in to replace her.

or

> Jair stood on the sidelines and saw that Kitty was getting tired. He realised it was time he substituted Kitty, and ran onto field to replace her.

Both these examples are contrary to how I'd expect the verb normally to be used, but I don't think I'd bat an eyelid if I saw them in print.